# Performance of a REST service proxy vs WCF SOAP proxy

Tags: c#, rest, soap

I've been getting performance results that I cannot explain, when comparing a client that consumes a REST service and a SOAP service. What I did is create a service proxy as follows:

REST:

```
WebHttpBinding webBinding = new WebHttpBinding();
webBinding.AllowCookies = true;
webBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;

CustomBinding custom = new CustomBinding(webBinding);

WebMessageEncodingBindingElement webMEBE = custom.Elements.Find<WebMessageEncodingBindingElement>();

webMEBE.ContentTypeMapper = new MyMapper();
webMEBE.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;

var factory = new WebChannelFactory<ITest>(custom, new Uri("http://localhost/Test"));
var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
```

SOAP:

```
endPointAddr = "net.tcp://" + textBox2.Text +
":8909/MyService";
tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
tcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
tcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
tcpBinding.TransactionFlow = false;
tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel =
    System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
    TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;

endpointAddress =
    new EndpointAddress(endPointAddr);

IService1 proxy =
    ChannelFactory<IService1>.CreateChannel(tcpBinding, endpointAddress);
```

Both `IService1` and `ITest` have one method that I use, `GetRequest()`, which returns an ~300Kb object. IService1.GetRequest() is an OperationContract, ITest.GetRequest() is a WebGet.

Once I open the channels in both cases I ran a tight loop of proxy.GetRequest(), to figure out how many Requests / s each can handle. The results were that if the test was on a local machine SOAP outperformed REST at 5:1, and over a network SOAP still outperformed REST by about 50%.

I do not understand why there is such a big difference.

Comment: Embarassing :S. Friday, was the first time I used either technology and I went from a tutorial that came up when I searched for WCF SOAP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is because of the binding you're using. You're using `net.tcp` as the protocol for your SOAP service, which uses a proprietary binary format for transporting messages. That means that non-WCF technologies won't be able to connect to your service. `WebHttp` is being used for the REST service, which is going to be much more compatible with other (non-.NET) technologies, but isn't going to have the same performance.

If you want a better "apples-to-apples" comparison of SOAP vs. REST performance, use a `WsHttpBinding` or `BasicHttpBinding` for your SOAP service.

Comment: That explains a lot. Issue is that I am doing these tests because we would like to switch to REST exactly because it doesn't require WCF. I'm just not sure we could take that kind of performance hit. Is there any platform agnostic technology that would give me speeds similar to what I'm getting with WCF?

Comment: @user No, it's a tradeoff between performance and interoperability. You're also going to lose all of the `WS-*` functionality, such as defining transaction scope, more security-oriented features, etc.